# In asp.net insert asp button usign HTML from Code Behind page using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying make dynamic table from database . Table Build dynamically by inserting html table code inserting place holder to get result like Grideview.

but one  insert asp control button..

Problem is in that button . that doesn't appear on page . other full table is display well

html.Append("     ");

```
public StringBuilder DataTableBuilder(DataSet ds)
{
    try
    {
        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Table start.
        html.Append("<div class='row container' style='font-size:large;'> " +
                    "   <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12'> " +
                    "       <div class='card  card-box'>  " +
                    "           <div class='card-head' >   " +
                    "           <header>New Student List</header> " +
                    "               <div class='tools'>   " +
                    "                   <a class='fa fa-repeat btn-color box-refresh' href='javascript:;'></a> " +
                    "                   <a class='t-collapse btn-color fa fa-chevron-down' href='javascript:;'></a> " +
                    "                   <a class='t-close btn-color fa fa-times' href='javascript:;'></a> " +
                    "               </div> " +
                    "           </div> " +
                    "           <div class='card-body '> " +
                    "               <div class='table-wrap' > " +
                    "                   <div class='table-responsive'> " +
                    "                       <table class='table display product-overview mb-30'  id='support_table' runat='server'> " +
                    "                           <thead >");


        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        //Building the Header row.
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<th style='text-align:center'>");
            html.Append(column.ColumnName);
            html.Append("</th>");
        }
        html.Append("<th style='text-align:center'>Edit</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody style='text-align:right'> ");

        //Building the Data rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("   <td> <asp:CheckBox ID='Selected" + row["ID"].ToString() + "' runat='server' AutoPostBack='true' OnCheckedChanged='Load_data' /> </td></tr>");

       //  "<asp:button id='id" + row["ID"].ToString() + "'  data-toggle='tooltip'  runat='server' AutoPostBack='true' OnClick='Load_data'  Text='Edit' / >  ============  html.Append("    <td><a onclick='Load_data("+ row["ID"].ToString()+ ")'  data-toggle='tooltip'  runat='server' AutoPostBack='true' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></a></td></tr>");
        }
        html.Append("</tbody> " +
            "                               </table> " +
            "                           </div> " +
            "                       </div> " +
            "                   </div> " +
            "               </div> " +
            "           </div> " +
            "       </div>");

        return html;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: html.Append("   <td> <asp:CheckBox ID='Selected" + row["ID"].ToString() + "' runat='server' AutoPostBack='true' OnCheckedChanged='Load_data' /> </td></tr>"); this code is not working

Comment: If you build html as string then you need to include *rendered* controls like `"<input type=\"checkbox\"... />`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537947/dynamically-insert-checkbox-into-a-table-in-asp-net-with-variable-number-of-fiel

Comment: You cannot render aspnet controls as a string.